# Replacing the query causing NavigationDuplicated error in Vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I need to remove the value from arrayed query parameter. Suppose, when query is

```
{
  item_ids: [ "12", "13" ],
  other_param: [ "alpha", "bravo" ]
}
```

my function `removeElementFromArrayedQueryParameter('item_ids', 13)` must turn query to:

```js
{
  item_ids: [ "12" ],
  other_param: [ "alpha", "bravo" ]
}
```

Implementation (TypeScript):

```js
function removeElementFromArrayedQueryParameter(key: string, value: string): void {

  /** 〔Theory〕 Preventing 'NavigationDuplicated: Navigating to current location ("/〇〇") is not allowed' */
  if (isEmptyObject(RoutingHelper.router.currentRoute.query)) {
    return;
  }

  if (!Array.isArray(RoutingHelper.router.currentRoute.query[key])) {
    return;
  }

  const updatedQuery: QueryParameters = {
    ...RoutingHelper.router.currentRoute.query as object
  };

  removeSingleElementFromArrayByPredicateMutably(
      updatedQuery[key] as Array<string>, (arrayElement: string): boolean => arrayElement === value
  );

  console.log(JSON.stringify(updatedQuery, null, 2)); // I checked: the element has been romoved

  // it's the router instance created by new VueRouter({})
  RoutingHelper.router.push({
    query: updatedQuery
  })
      .catch((error: Error): void => {
        console.error(error)
      });
}

function isEmptyObject(potentialObject: unknown): potentialObject is object {
  if (typeof potentialObject !== "object" || potentialObject === null) {
    return false;
  }
  return Object.entries(potentialObject as {[key: string]: unknown}).length === 0;
}
```

Although the removing of target element from `updatedQuery` successful (checked by manual testing), I have console error:

```
{
  "_name": "NavigationDuplicated",
  "name": "NavigationDuplicated",
  "message": "Navigating to current location (\"/page?item_ids=12\") is not allowed"
}
```

"message" in console error contains right target location, but actually one of `item_ids` has not been removed from URI.

The console error is right about route name is same, but I don't going to redirect on same page: I just want to remove one query parameter. `router.push` casts similar error.

### Update

Please note that TypeScript does not allow to write as

```
this.$router.replace({
  ...this.$router.currentRoute,
  query
 });
```

```
TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(location: RawLocation): Promise<Route>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ query: Dictionary<string | (string | null)[] | null | undefined>; path: string; name?: string |
null | undefined; hash: string; params: Dictionary<string>; fullPath: string; matched: RouteRecord[]; redirectedFrom?: s
tring | undefined; meta?: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RawLocation'.
      Type '{ query: Dictionary<string | (string | null)[] | null | undefined>; path: string; name?: string | null | und
efined; hash: string; params: Dictionary<string>; fullPath: string; matched: RouteRecord[]; redirectedFrom?: string | un
defined; meta?: any; }' is not assignable to type 'Location'.
        Types of property 'name' are incompatible.
          Type 'string | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
            Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(location: RawLocation, onComplete?: Function | undefined, onAbort?: ErrorHandler | undefined): void
', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ query: Dictionary<string | (string | null)[] | null | undefined>; path: string; name?: string |
null | undefined; hash: string; params: Dictionary<string>; fullPath: string; matched: RouteRecord[]; redirectedFrom?: s
tring | undefined; meta?: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RawLocation'.
      Type '{ query: Dictionary<string | (string | null)[] | null | undefined>; path: string; name?: string | null | und
efined; hash: string; params: Dictionary<string>; fullPath: string; matched: RouteRecord[]; redirectedFrom?: string | un
defined; meta?: any; }' is not assignable to type 'Location'.
        Types of property 'name' are incompatible.
          Type 'string | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
            Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
```

If the are no mistake in TypeScript types, above solution is not safe.

```
this.$router.replace({
   ...this.$router.name === null ? {} : RoutingHelper.router.currentRoute,
   query: updatedQuery
})
```

does not fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You should update your new route like this

```js
function removeFromQuery(route, queryName, queryValue)
{
  const query = Object.assign({}, route.query);
  if (queryName in query)
  {
    const idx = query[queryName].indexOf(queryValue);
    if (idx !== -1) 
    {
      query[queryName].splice(idx, 1);
      this.$router.replace({
        ...this.$router.currentRoute,
        query
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Would you please to enplane my mistake?

Comment: I do not use TypeScript so I do not know whether you have mistake in your code. My point is that you should only change the route if the code actually removed the given `queryValue` from the current route.

Comment: "should only change the route": you mean "create a deep copy of '$router.currentRoute' with updated query"?

Comment: It does not matter whether the copy is deep or not - what matters is whether the `currentRoute.fullPath` is different than `newRoute.fullPath` or not.

Answer (score 0):

The `updatedQuery` query is not the deep clone of `RoutingHelper.router.currentRoute.query`. Below code is not enough to create the deep copy of `query`:

```
const updatedQuery: QueryParameters = {
   ...RoutingHelper.router.currentRoute.query as object
};
```

So, when execute

```
RoutingHelper.router.push({
  query: updatedQuery
})
```

we don't subtitute `query` to new value. That why error occurs.

Use `lodash` or other libraries provides deep cloning, or use own implementation of deep cloning.